Data not getting ingested into array type objects in Adobe Experience Platform
I am trying to invest data through CSV file into array type object fields in a schema in Adobe experience platform.But the data is not getting ingested although it's not showing any error while ingesting.
Array type objects:
Cool Numbers - Integer type
Favorite Choice - String type
Sample data in csv file:
Cool Numbers
"2|26"
"5|63|74"
Favorite Choice
"ic|t"
"t"
When I am loading the CSV file manually into schema,I am creating calculated field for both of them like
to_array(true,split(Cool_Numbers,"|"))
and mapping it to the corresponding target field.
Validation is coming fine but when I finish the workflow and check the processed data,it shows blank in both the fields in the dataset.
